# Eclipse not functioning after first Scala Build

Tags: java, android, eclipse, scala, proguard

I"m trying to create an android using Scala IDE and SBT Proguard. I'm able to get the application to build and compile originally but after the first build Eclipse stop working. It started giving syntax complaining that my import should end with a semicolon.

I'm also getting the following errors

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
SBT builder crashed while compiling. The error message is 'class StringContext does not have a member f'. Check Error Log for details.  scala       Unknown Scala Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Error in Scala compiler: class StringContext does not have a member f   scala       Unknown Scala Problem
```

and the following warning.

```
More than one scala library found in the build path (C:/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/284/1/.cp/lib/scala-library.jar, C:/dev/scala/libs/scala_library.min.jar).This is not an optimal configuration, try to limit to one Scala library in the build path. scala       Unknown Scala Classpath Problem
```

[image]

Comment: Try removing the Scala Library classpath container from your Eclipse project, you can check this link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-ide-user/TvBZegGQ2uQ

Comment: @MrMins that get rid of the warning but the errors still persist.

Answer (score 4):

Can you confirm you are in the Scala perspective and not the Java?

From the image it appears you are missing the Scala libraries. Have you tried adding them?
To do this, right click on the project and select Scala, then "Add Scala Library to Build Path"

[image]

Comment: Yes I'm using the Scala perspective

Comment: No problem, figured it might be useful

Comment: Can you share your project files? SBT build, plugins and build.properties?

Comment: I havent created any SBT files. When I tried to generate the project using gen-android eclipse would not import the project. So I created it via the new application wizard in eclipse

Comment: I was just able to rebuild by closing the project and reopening it, not the IDE